# Best way to authenticate powershell script for Azure resource managment

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight, azure-resource-manager

To authenticate to Azure and use the Azure Resource Manager cmdlets, I currently use the methods outlined [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx), namely using an Azure Active Directory account, encrypting the password, storing the encrypted string in a text file, and reading that into a credential object when using it in the script.

But I get the sense that maybe I should be using management certificates instead.

There is a documented method to use a publish settings file, but apparently that doesn't work for AzureRm cmdlets, only older cmdlets.

I have seen examples for using Powershell to create an application_id and service principal, and for authenticating a C# app, for instance, but I can't seem to find anything showing how to use management certificates for authentication in a powershell script, to use AzureRm cmdlets.

Maybe the secure string password storage method is the right one.  But I don't have a good sense for that.

What do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it? It depends what is important to you. Ease of use, security, scripting?

Microsoft Azure Tooling (Visual Studio, Azure Powershell and CLI) lately moved to a more fine-granular, role-based access control approach based on Azure AD. This is currently a pretty good way to do it, since Management certificates allow owners to manage at subscription level and have proven to be rather difficult in environments like Azure Automation.

Refs

- https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-certs-create/#what-are-management-certificates
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/03/17/rbac-and-the-azure-resource-manager.aspx
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-rbac/#concepts

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to Service Principal

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/